# Can't convert int to string

Tags: python, string, int

I'm trying to run this code but it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/gess.py", line 29, in <module>
 print('arasworia, chemi chafiqrebuli cifri iyo ' + cif)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Here is the code:

```
import random
guessTaken = 0
print(' ra gqvia? ')
sax = input()
cif = random.randint(1, 10)
print('Gamarjoba ' + sax + ' me vfiqrob cifrs, romelic aris 1 dan 10-mde! da gaqs 3  cda ')
while guessTaken < 3:
print(' chaifiqre cifri')
vard = input()
vard = int(vard)

guessTaken = guessTaken + 1

if vard < cif:
    print( ' Ufro dabal cifrs vfiqrob ')

if vard > cif:
    print( ' ufro magal cifrs vqirob ' )

if vard == cif:
    break

if vard == cif:
guessTaken = str(guessTaken)
print('gilocav ' + sax + 'shen gamoicane cifr ' + guessTaken + ' cdashi!')

if vard != cif:
cif == str(cif)
print('arasworia, chemi chafiqrebuli cifri iyo ' + cif)
```

Answer (score 2):

The

```
cif == str(cif)
```

should be

```
cif = str(cif)
```

In Python, `==` is comparison and `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str()` inside the `print` function:

```
print('arasworia, chemi chafiqrebuli cifri iyo ' + str(cif))
```

Also, note that `==` is used to check equality. Use `=` for assignment. Use

```
cif = str(cif)
```

instead of

```
cif == str(cif)
```

Comment: This should have been a +1. The comparison operator error is the solution.